# Why is this a valid approach for updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), it mentioned that next state shouldn't be directly computed from current state. This is because state updates are asynchronous, so you can't be assured that you are using the correct value of state.

However, in the official [tutorial](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010), you will see this function:

```
handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();

    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }

    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";

    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([
        {
          squares: squares
        }
      ]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
   });
}
```

You can see that the variable `history` is a function of `state.history` and `state.stepNumber`. Isn't this a contradiction of what was mentioned in the docs, or am I missing something?

Comment: May be a case of over-simplification for the tutorial. Or may be a documentation bug. If it's the later, it can be reported on the [React github](https://github.com/facebook/react/).

Comment: I can suppose the handleClick (callback of a click) will be the state trigger to change... then, access the value appling a slice, will copy the part of the needed history array, and the computation will not suffer with that.

Comment: It's an onclick handler, so there isn't a risk of batched state updates, and batched state updates wouldn't matter here anyways, since if you made multiple moves so quickly that they get batched, having one of them get lost and overwritten with the other move wouldn't matter (and would probably be the desired effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People get a little too dogmatic about it in my opinion, but there have been enough hard to trace bugs that maybe it's justified. Ultimately, you have to know **why** its recommended in order to know **if** its ok not to in special cases.

#### Why is it recommended?

State updates are asynchronous and can be batched, and you may be using stale values if you update state multiple times and one or more of your updates are based on previous values. In a functional component, you have the same risks do to stale closures.

Example where state *should* be updated 5 times, but is only incremented once:

Functional component example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  
  const onClick = () => {
    [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(() => {
      console.log('update');
      setValue(value + 1);
    });
  }
   
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Update 5 times</button>
      <div>Count: {value}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Class component example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  }
  
  onClick = () => {
    [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(() => {
      this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Update 5 times</button>
        <div>Count: {this.state.count}</div>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

#### Is it ok to use normal state updates based on previous state?

It depends on your use case. If you know for an absolute certainty that you will only update state once, then technically it's safe. The problem is, while it may be safe today, tomorrow you or another developer may unknowingly change that...

At the end of the day, I think you have to ask yourself: "Do I gain any extra benefit from not using a functional update?", if so then understand the risks of future bugs and go for it (you should probably document it heavily too). But almost every time, the answer will be *just use the functional update*.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, there must be a middle ground. If we follow the functional form of `setState` in this case, wouldn't we have to place all the logic concerning `history` inside `setState`? That doesn't seem very clean, and I doubt that's how it should be done.

Comment: Yes you're right, and I'm not necessarily saying that needs to happen here. The scope of the update is limited which means so is the risk. My point is to understand what the pros and cons are of each method. In this case, maybe readability outweighs the risk of a future update breaking things? There's no absolute answer until bugs are involved.

Comment: Agreed. Although I just managed to think of doing this in a clean way: using external state update functions. Dan has a great tweet about this but can't link atm since I'm on mobile. Essentially, you use the functional update, but split those into functions external to the component. So you can keep your component clean and hide the details. Plus, you can always assure you have latest state.

Answer (score 1):

because this: `const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);` isn't actually mutating any state. it's just assigning it to a const for the local function to use. it's not actually manipulating the state itself

a few lines below it uses `this.setState({})` to directly change state in the standard way

the assigning to a const is different than if you just did this:  `this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1)` which would be directly manipulating it